# mysql query takes 4 min to execute

Tags: mysql

**Table 1.**

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_users` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`landingpage` int(11) DEFAULT '8',
`user_role_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`user_parent_role` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`bank_branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
`firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `user_role_id` (`user_role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=281 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='الموظفين';
```

**Table 2.**

```
CREATE TABLE `application_activity` (
`activityid` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dataid` text,
`datatable` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`userid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`activitytype` char(1) DEFAULT 'I',
`activitytime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`activityip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`activitydevice` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`activityid`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=152862 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='نشاط التطبيق';
```

**Query I am executing.**

```
SELECT admin_users.`firstname`,admin_users.`lastname`,admin_users.`id`, branches.`branch_name`,
            (SELECT COUNT(activityid) FROM application_activity WHERE userid=admin_users.`id`) AS cnt,
            (SELECT activitytype FROM application_activity WHERE userid=admin_users.`id` ORDER BY activityid DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS activitytype,
            (SELECT datatable FROM application_activity WHERE userid=admin_users.`id` ORDER BY activityid DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS datatable,
            (SELECT activitytime FROM application_activity WHERE userid=admin_users.`id` ORDER BY activityid DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS activitytime
            FROM admin_users
            JOIN branches ON branches.`branch_id`=admin_users.`branch_id`
            HAVING cnt > 0
            ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Table 1 have 100 records of users and Table 2 have more then 100k records of application activity.

when i execute query it will take 4min for giving result.

Comment: Have you looked at _EXPLAIN_?

Comment: what i need to explain, i am new in database so guide me

Comment: Google for mysql explain command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

This is your query:

```
SELECT au.`firstname`, au.`lastname`, au.`id`, b.`branch_name`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM application_activity aa WHERE aa.userid = admin_users.`id`) AS cnt,
            (SELECT aa.activitytype FROM application_activity aa WHERE aa.userid = au.`id` ORDER BY aa.activityid DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS activitytype,
            (SELECT aa.datatable FROM application_activity aa WHERE aa.userid = au.`id` ORDER BY aa.activityid DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS datatable,
            (SELECT aa.activitytime FROM application_activity aa WHERE aa.userid = au.id` ORDER BY aa.activityid DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS activitytime
FROM admin_users au JOIN
     branches b
     ON b.`branch_id` = au.`branch_id`
HAVING cnt > 0
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

You need appropriate indexes.  One is on `branches(branch_id)` -- but you might have this already.

The second is `application_activity(userid, activityid)`.

I strongly recommend that when *all* columns in correlated subqueries be qualified with the table alias.

Comment: i did but result is same, when i commit  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM application_activity aa WHERE aa.userid = au.`id`) AS cnt this result comes to quick